# Using swift and Mapkit, display route between user's current location to a specific location

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, cllocationmanager

Upon the app opening, I'd like to draw a route between user's current location to a specific location using MapKit in Swift.

I know how to request/get a hold of the users current location:

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  originalTopMargin = topMarginConstraint.constant
   locationManager.delegate = self
  locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
   if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
    locationManager.requestLocation()
  }
}
```

What I don't know is, where does the code to actually calculate and display the route belong?  Would it be in this function?

```
func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[AnyObject])
```

I've read the Ray Wenderlich Mapkit tutorials and many, many other sites, I'm having a tough time finding an answer to my specific question.  Everything I've found so far has useful information, but doesn't quite have what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this in a long time - but what you want to do is use the MKDirections API.

Basically you create an MKDirectionsRequest object and you can use this to eventually get a list of steps to reach your destination. You can also use this to get an MKPolyLine object to render this on your map etc.

Here is a link to a tutorial. It is in objective-C but it should be relatively easy to translate the code.http://www.devfright.com/mkdirections-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks Rufus.  The example provided is a good one, but it doesn't appear to handle a few things.  

I was hoping to have the route drawn as the app is launching (not after a button press).  

I can't tell from the example which function the code to actually calculate and display the route belongs in (for Swift).

Comment: "Implementing MKDirections and MKDirectionsRequest" is the section in the linked article that explains it. The entire article in general goes through the whole process explaining it step by step. If you read it carefully and try to understand it - you should be able to work out what you need to do.